# Curl requesting more url than set

Tags: php, http, url, curl

Here is the curl function which requests the url.

```
function get_result( $nodes )
    {
        $node_count = count($nodes);

        $curl_arr = array();
        $master = curl_multi_init();

        for($i = 0; $i < $node_count; $i++)
        {
            $url = $nodes[$i];
            $curl_arr[$i] = curl_init($url);
            curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i], CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 180);
            curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i], CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 180);
            curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i], CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip");
            curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i], CURLOPT_PROXY, '127.0.0.1:8888');
            curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i], CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
            curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i], CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; rv:2.2) Gecko/20110201');
            curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i], CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
            curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i], CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
            curl_multi_add_handle($master, $curl_arr[$i]);
        }

    do {
        curl_multi_exec($master,$running);
        curl_multi_select($master, 5.0);
    } while($running > 0);


    $output = "";
    for($i = 0; $i < $node_count; $i++)
    {
        $output .= curl_multi_getcontent( $curl_arr[$i]  );
    }
    return $output;

    }

    $offset = 0;

    function select_data()
    {
        global $conn_to_sql;
        global $offset;
        $select_statement = $conn_to_sql->prepare("SELECT url FROM url_list LIMIT 5 OFFSET $offset");
        $select_statement->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $offset += 5;
        $select_statement->execute();
        return $select_statement->fetchAll();
    }

while( select_data() )
{
    $datas = select_data();

    foreach ( $datas as $data )
    {
        $dat = $data["url"];
        $nodes[] = $dat;
    }
    get_result( $nodes )
}
```

`get_result` is called from a loop with an `array of 5 URLs`. (URLs are loaded from table with `LIMIT 5` and `OFFSET INCREASES BY 5`) but every time number of requests increase by 5.

At first time `get_result` requests 5 URLs.

Next time it requests 10 URLs `(Next 10 URLs without duplication)`, and then 15 URLs `(Next 15 URLs without duplication)`, this goes on by 20, 25, 30, 35 ...

How do i know that requests are increasing ? all the traffic goes the proxy(`FIDDLER`);

get_result should request only 5 URLs every time but this is not happening. how to solve this ?

Comment: Post the code for the DB query and while loop. I suspect a problem somewhere there.

Comment: "Next 10 URLs without duplication" then the error is in the code the generates the url array. You need to show that code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the `$nodes` array is collecting too many results.

```
while( select_data() )
{
    $datas = select_data();
    $nodes=array();/*reset $nodes array here*/
    foreach ( $datas as $data )
    {
        $dat = $data["url"];
        $nodes[] = $dat;
    }
    get_result( $nodes )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your while is execute after your query. So, your query is sending 1 by 1 url and not 5 by 5...